# Inkscape CLI batch conversion of svg to eps using terminal / CLI

Tags: command-line, snap, inkscape

I'm trying to batch convert svg vector files to EPS files but having trouble.

Command I'm using:

```
for file in /tmp/0/*.svg; do inkscape "$file" -o "${file%svg}eps" --export-ignore-filters --export-ps-level=3; done
```

Error I'm getting:

```
Gtk-Message: 12:09:52.418: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 12:09:52.420: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:948538): WARNING **: 12:09:52.682: Can't open file: /tmp/0/test20016.svg (doesn't exist)

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:948538): WARNING **: 12:09:52.682: Can't open file: /tmp/0/test20016.svg (doesn't exist)
ink_file_open: '/tmp/0/test20016.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /tmp/0/test20016.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
Gtk-Message: 12:09:52.956: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 12:09:52.958: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:948666): WARNING **: 12:09:53.223: Can't open file: /tmp/0/test20022.svg (doesn't exist)

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:948666): WARNING **: 12:09:53.224: Can't open file: /tmp/0/test20022.svg (doesn't exist)
ink_file_open: '/tmp/0/test20022.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /tmp/0/test20022.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
```

**The file is there and can be opened using the GUI of inkscape**

I'm using the snap version of Inkscape:
**Inkscape 1.2.2 (b0a8486541, 2022-12-01, custom)**

```
inkscape /tmp/0/test20016.svg
```

Fails to open file:

```
Gtk-Message: 12:30:49.665: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Gtk-Message: 12:30:49.667: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:966787): WARNING **: 12:30:49.981: Can't open file: /tmp/0/test20016.svg (doesn't exist)

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:966787): WARNING **: 12:30:49.981: Can't open file: /tmp/0/test20016.svg (doesn't exist)
ink_file_open: '/tmp/0/test20016.svg' cannot be opened!
InkscapeApplication::document_open: Failed to open: /tmp/0/test20016.svg
ConcreteInkscapeApplication::on_open: failed to create document!
```

Other commands work as expected:

```
$ for file in /tmp/0/*.svg; do ls "$file"; done 
/tmp/0/test20016.svg 
/tmp/0/test20022.svg
```

I did a `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module` but still has issues with the **canberra-gtk-module**

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS:
**Linux sys76 5.15.0-57-generic #63~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 30 13:40:16 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Comment: That's odd. Can there be a process deleting these files between the moment when the `for file in /tmp/0/*.svg` list is populated and the moment the inkscape command runs? Is this inskcape-specific? Does `for file in /tmp/0/*.svg; do ls "$file"; done` work as expected?

Comment: @terdon when I do a `/tmp/0/svg$ for file in /tmp/0/*.svg; do ls "$file"; done`
I get:

`/tmp/0/test20016.svg`
`/tmp/0/test20022.svg`

Comment: And does `inkscape /tmp/0/test20016.svg` open the file normally?

Comment: @terdon  No it fails I updated the question to include output.  But inkscape will execute when inkscape is run from the terminal

Comment: Hmm. I've never used snaps, but I know they use some sort of squashfs file system. It might be that from the command line, the `/tmp` refers to a different location and cannot be understood from within the snap but there is some sort of compatibility layer when you do it from the GUI. But I'm clutching at straws here and imagining things, I have no idea if I'm right.

Comment: Does `cd /tmp/0/svg && inkscape test20016.svg` do any better?

Comment: @terdon That  fails to run I even tried putting the files in my home directory to see if that would help but inkscape doesn't seem to launch with a file parameter from the terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141979/discussion-between-terdon-and-rick-t).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks goes to **terdon** for working with me on this.

Just tried it with the appimage and it worked....**(so this snap has issues with some CLI commands)**

Command I used to get it to work.

1- Download the **appimage**
https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.2.2/gnulinux/appimage/dl/

2- `chmod u+x Inkscape-b0a8486-x86_64.AppImage`

3- Run the command:

```
for file in /tmp/0/svg/*.svg; do ./Inkscape-b0a8486-x86_64.AppImage "$file" -o "${file%svg}eps" --export-ignore-filters --export-ps-level=3; done
```